# Add marquee dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to add a marquee to my HTML dynamically. This is the function I have created

```
                var element = document.getElementById('overflow');
                var parentElement = document.getElementById('countheader');
                if (element) {
                    var overflow = isElementOverflowing(element, parentElement);
                    if (overflow && !element.classList.contains('marquee')) {
                        element.className += "marquee";
                    } else if (!overflow) {
                        element.classList.remove('marquee');
                    }
                }

function isElementOverflowing(element, parentElement) {
        return parentElement.clientWidth <= element.clientWidth;
    }
```

In the CSS file I have the styling as

```
 #countheader{   
        background-color: #e9df8b;
        width: fit-content;
        white-space: nowrap;
        min-width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-left: 11px!important;
        max-width: 1266px!important;
    }
    #overflow{
        max-width: 1266px!important;
    }
```

#HTML

```
 <div class="page-content" style="background-color: {{isDarkMode ? '#000000' : '#FFFFFF'}}">

                    <!-- Item Count Card-->

                    <div class="order-card item-card"
                         ng-if="currentStation.get('enableItemCount') && viewTitle === 'Open Orders' && currentStation.get('itemCountFilters').length > 0 && itemsCount.length > 0">
                       
                        <div class="card-header"  id="countheader">
                                <div id="overflow">
                                    <b class="item-heading">Total Count</b>
                                    <span  class="item-count" ng-repeat="item in itemsCount">{{item.name}}({{item.quantity}})</span>
                                </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                    <!-- Item Count Card -->
```

But in some cases, I am seeing that the text overflows the parent div in the UI but in the function `isOverflowing` it is still showing parent element width greater and so the marquee does not gets added in the class. Is there a better way to find the height of the parent div and child div content?

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML for this?